# BertForTokenClassification Has Extra Output

Tags: pytorch, bert-language-model, huggingface-transformers, named-entity-recognition

I am using PyTorch's BertForTokenClassification pretrained model to do custom word tagging (not NER or POS, but essentially the same). There are 20 different possible tags (using BIO scheme): 9 B's, 9 I's, and an O. Despite there being 19 possible tags, the feed-forward layer that is added on top of BERT has 20 tags. I have used other datasets, too, and the result is the same: there is always one more output than the number of classes. Can anyone tell me why this is?

Comment: This doesn't seem to be the case. Are you sure the `num_labels` attribute of the model configuration `model.config` is set to 19? If not, how are you initializing the model?

Comment: @KonstantinosKokos The number was not set manually. It was set based on the number of unique labels in the dataset (which I verified manually).

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out. The reason is because I was not accounting for the `PAD` token.